# A simple image popup

Tags: android, dictionary, hashmap, android-imageview

So, I'm adding a new feature to my scavenger hunt app which is basically the ability to show a picture for a clue.  By tapping on the clue text, I go to an ImageView Activity to show the picture dependent on that clue.  The problem is, I don't know how to make this work.  I tried doing a Map/HashMap combo....

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("info", R.drawable.clue0);
map.put("goebel", R.drawable.clue1);
map.put("church", R.drawable.clue2);
map.put("confed", R.drawable.clue3);
map.put("ban", R.drawable.clue4);
map.put("jr", R.drawable.clue5);
map.put("ohara", R.drawable.clue6);
map.put("db", R.drawable.clue7);
```

and then populating the picture with...

```
imgClue.setImageResource(map.get("goebel"));
```

Clicking on the text clue has this code:

```
txtClue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cluePic = new Intent(FCRun.this, imgClue.class);
                Intent imgClue;
                cluePic.putExtras(imgClue);
            }

        });
```

The ImageView Activity code (so far) is this...

```
public class imgClue extends Activity{
public static ImageView iClue;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.imgclue);

}

public static void setImageResource(Integer integer) {

    }}
```

My proximity alerts pass an ID to denote the location being displayed.  I use  Switch(ID)/Case to set what text is shown on the screen based on the location.  I was hoping I could just add another line in the Case statements to tell what picture is to be displayed.

So my question is, am I going about this the wrong way or is my code just completely wrong?

The code won't compile, as it just doesn't like the periods in my MAP statements.

Thanks,
Hendo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't compile because of these two lines:

```
 Intent imgClue;
 cluePic.putExtras(imgClue);
```

delete them and replace them with

```
 startActivity(cluePic);
```

---

This is also wrong `imgClue.setImageResource(map.get("goebel"));` you should not set the result from the map (i.e. the Integer drawable resource)` as a static method. You should pass it through the intent, for example:

cluePic.putExtra("MyImageKey", map.get("goebel"));

then in your activity (imgClue) inside `onCreate` you would do

```
 int imageDrawableResource = getIntent().getIntExtra("MyImageKey", 0);
```

---

Although your code isn't perfect, it is a perfectly fine way to do it. :-)

---

To make your code more understandable to yourself later on I would advise these changes:

- change `Map<String, Integer> map` to `Map<String, Integer> cluePictures`
- change `txtClue` to `clueTextView`
- change `Intent cluePic` to `Intent cluePictureIntent`
- change `imgClue extends Activity` to `ImageClueActivity extends Activity`
- remove the static keyword from `public static ImageView iClue` and make private : `private ImageView clueImageView`

Comment: in this line, 'cluePic.putExtra("MyImageKey", map.get("goebel"));' isn't "goebel" the image key?  I guess I don't understand what the "MyImageKey" that you're referring to, is.

Comment: Thank you for your help and for replying so quickly.  :-)

Comment: @DaveHenderson there are two keys in this line. You are correct `"goebel"` is the key for your map. You are then putting the value from your map into the `Intent` and using another key to send that to next activity :-)